# htaccess two folder rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I already use this htaccess rule already and it works

```
RewriteRule ^community/profile/([^/]+) community/profile/profile.php?id=$1
```

So, when I'm on a profile page for example `website.com/community/profile/example-user`, I will be able to extract the user from the id=$1 part.

I need to extend this to two folders, where example-user can have 2 sub-folders, like `website.com/community/profile/example-user/folder1/` and `website.com/community/profile/example-user/folder 2/`

I tried the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^community/profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+) community/profile/profile.php?id=$1&car=$2
```

Unfortunately though, this breaks the whole rule and it doesn't work. I got the idea from this post https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65785/rewrite-up-to-three-folders-into-three-query-string-parameters-to-a-php-script

Also, I tried

```
RewriteRule ^community/profile/../([^/]+) community/profile/profile?id=$1&car=$2
```

Also didn't work.

To make things clear, if one only goes to the 'first' folder, in this example it is `/example-user/`, the car variable should just be empty. How can I write this rule so that it will put that second 'folder' into a second variable so I can extract it later in my php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure to use anchor `$` for precise matching in regex
- Include dot in your character class to avoid matching it again

**Rules :**

```
RewriteRule ^community/profile/([^/.]+)/?$ community/profile/profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^community/profile/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ community/profile/profile.php?id=$1&car=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```